# How to align all description labels with section

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, description

I am using this code

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, paper=portrait, pagesize=auto]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}   
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{orange}{HTML}{FFC296}
\begin{document} 
\SetLabelAlign{rightbox}{\hss\llap{#1\quad}}
\setlist[description,1]{align=rightbox,labelsep=0pt,leftmargin=0pt}
\section{Student 93b427156c}
\begin{description}
    \item[number] 93b4s27156c              
    \item[name] Note that this analysis of a formative as a pair of sets of features is necessary
to impose an interpretation on an important distinction in language use.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

and its giving this output

[image]

Is there any way to align all the labels under Student Section  not the left side of Section

Comment: Would you please provide an image of the output you're after, since it's not very clear from your description what you mean by "align all the labels under Student Section"?

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to use your code, and then to use an additional list (with the help of the `changepage` package), as a wrapper, to get the desired leftmargin. The newly defined environment `mdesc` needs to know the widest label, to make the necessary calculations; this longest label must be given as a mandatory argument to the environment:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, paper=portrait, pagesize=auto]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}   
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{changepage}

\setlist[description,1]{labelsep=0pt,leftmargin=0pt}

\newenvironment{mdesc}[1]
{
  \begin{adjustwidth}{\widthof{{\bfseries#1}\quad}}{0pt}
  \begin{description}[before={
    \renewcommand\makelabel[1]{%
      \llap{\makebox[\widthof{\bfseries#1}][l]{\hfill\bfseries####1}\quad}}}]
}
{\end{description}\end{adjustwidth}}

\begin{document} 

\section{Student 93b427156c}

\begin{mdesc}{number}
    \item[number] 93b4s27156c              
    \item[name] Note that this analysis of a formative as a pair of sets of features is necessary
to impose an interpretation on an important distinction in language use.
\end{mdesc}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to directly align the paragraph with the section name. Someone else probably will. Instead, here is a way to mock up a similar layout, using `longtable`. See what you think.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, paper=portrait, pagesize=auto]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\definecolor{orange}{HTML}{FFC296}
\begin{document} 

\begin{longtable}[l]{ l l p{10cm}}
\textbf{{\Large 1}} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{{\Large Student 93b4s27156c}}} \\[2ex]
  & \textbf{number} & 93b4s27156c \\[2ex] 
  & \textbf{name} & Note that this analysis of a formative as a pair of sets of features is necessary to impose an interpretation on an important distinction in language use.h \\[2ex] 
\end{longtable}

%\SetLabelAlign{rightbox}{\hss\llap{#1\quad}}
%\setlist[description,1]{align=rightbox,labelsep=0pt,leftmargin=0pt}
\section{Student 93b427156c}
\begin{description}
\item[number] 93b4s27156c              
\item[name] Note that this analysis of a formative as a pair of sets of features is necessary to impose an interpretation on an important distinction in language use.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

And this is the result (with what you originally had, below it.):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have the framework already in place- the only thing to change is the section formatting. The [`titlesec`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/titlesec) is very helpful here- the only thing I had to add was

```
% custom section
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\llap{\thesection\hskip.5cm}}
{0pt}
{}
```

Here's the output

[image: screenshot]

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: on}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}   
\usepackage{titlesec}

% custom section
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\llap{\thesection\hskip.5cm}}
{0pt}
{}

\begin{document} 
\SetLabelAlign{rightbox}{\hss\llap{#1\quad}}
\setlist[description,1]{align=rightbox,labelsep=0pt,leftmargin=0pt}
\section{Student 93b427156c}
\begin{description}
    \item[number] 93b4s27156c              
    \item[name] Note that this analysis of a formative as a pair of sets of features is necessary
    to impose an interpretation on an important distinction in language use.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: i tired that ans its not working for me